# Why isn't Axios method running?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, axios, jest-mock-axios

I have the following vue app that allows a user to login.
I am running a unit test that should login but axios won't run when the submit method is triggered.

The Submit method being called by button trigger in the test:

```
methods: {
submit() {

  var name = this.username.value.replace(/ /g, '%20')
  var url = 'http://localhost:8080/properties'

  axios.get(
    url,  
    {      
    auth: 
    {
      username: name, 
      password: this.password.value
      
    }})
    .then((res) =>{
      if(res.data.CurMember.name == this.username.value 
      && name !='' && this.password != '')
      {
        this.navigateToHome()
      }
      else
      {
        this.invalidLogin = true;
      }
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
      console.error(error)
    })
  },

navigateToHome() {
  this.$router.push({name: "HomePage"});
},
```

The test:

```
import BasicLogin from '@/views/BasicLogin.vue'
import {shallowMount, mount, flushPromises} from "@vue/test-utils"
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import axios from 'axios'

const mockDataCorrectLogin = 
        [{
            'authType': 'string',
            'curMember': {
                'name': 'bossman',
                'pass': 'bigboss!!',
                'role': 'string'
            },
            'version': "string"
        }]

describe('BasicLogin.vue', () => 
{
let wrapper = null

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(BasicLogin, 
    {
        propsData:
        {
           //data go here
           usernameValue: '',
           passwordValue: '',
           
        },
    })
}),

it('Login as bossman, validate routing worked', async () => {
    
    const mockRoute = {
        params: {
            id: 1
        }
    }
    const mockRouter = {
        push: jest.fn()
    }
    const wrapper = mount(BasicLogin, {
        global: {
            mocks: {
                $route: mockRoute, 
                $router: mockRouter
            }
        }
    })


    const inputFieldUser = wrapper.get('[type="text"]').element
    inputFieldUser.value = 'bossman'
    expect(inputFieldUser.value).toBe('bossman')

    const inputFieldPass = wrapper.get('[type="password"]').element
    inputFieldPass.value = 'bigboss!!'
    expect(inputFieldPass.value).toBe('bigboss!!')

  
    jest.mock('axios', () => ({
        get: () => Promise.resolve(mockDataCorrectLogin)
    }))

    //This is where the submit is being called
    await wrapper.vm.submit();

    await flushPromises()
    expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({"name": "HomePage"})
    
 })
})
```

So why is the axios call being totally ignored in the submit method?
This is the error message displayed mockRouter was never pushed because the axios call was never made

```
 FAIL tests/unit/BasicLogin.spec.js
 ● BasicLogin.vue › Login as bossman, validate routing worked

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0

88 |
89 |         await flushPromises()
> 90 |         expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
 |                                 ^
91 |         expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({"name": "HomePage"})
92 |         
93 |     })

at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/BasicLogin.spec.js:90:33)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Because you can't affect top-level import with jest.mock inside a test. The problem would be more clear if you asserted if axios.get mock was called (it wasn't).

Comment: @EstusFlask Are you suggesting to remove the "jest.mock('axios'..." from inside my test and move it somewhere else in the spec.js file? for example up to the same location as the mockDataCorrectLogin variable? Thanks in advance

Comment: More specifically, right below `import` statements.

Comment: @EstusFlask This answer worked for me. Thanks a lot. But I did want to ask a follow up: 
If you wanted to mock different data sets, say I changed the json variable mockDataCorrectLogin to mockDataInCorrectLogin to simulate a incorrect login, how could I change the jest mock so it uses this variable instead when it's outside of my test? Would I just copy paste the jest.mock('axios'... function with the incorrect login data?

Comment: @EstusFlask Also, if you would like to post your comment as an answer I can mark it as the correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jest.mock` is hoisted in order to affect imports. In order for `jest.mock` to affect top-level `import`, it should be located at top level outside a test, it cannot be hoisted higher than a scope where it's used.

Functions exports need to be mocked with `jest.fn()`, the implementation can be changed per test with spy API:

```
axios.get.mockResolvedValue(mockDataCorrectLogin)
```

If a mock is needed per test, `jest.mock` can be located inside a test, a module needs to be be re-imported after it. This is only needed if non-function exports need to be mocked, or a module produces side effects that need to be reapplied.